# How to change the color of scrollbar in textview

Tags: android, textview, android-scrollview

I am using scrollbar in textview. I want to change the color of scrollbar when it is on focus.

Answer (score 3):

```
<item name="android:scrollbarSize">4dp</item>
<item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@color/scrollbar_thumb</item>
```

Comment: when it is not on focus I want to change to one color and onfocus different color

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [ColorStateList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList) for this if I'm not mistaking in combination with the `android:scrollbarThumbVertical` attribute: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbarThumbVertical